# cant get a with a while loop inside a while loop to work

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
while loop == True:                                                                             #creates loop, and uses previously defined 'loop'
    try:
        ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? "))      #asks question and requires a user input
        correct = (ans == num1 * num2)
        if correct:
            invtimer()
            print("You are correct! ")
            break                                                                               #if the answer is correct, it prints 'You are correct!' and breaks to avoid the loop
        else:
            invtimer()
   while loop == True:
            showans = input('''Wrong answer.
Would you like to see the answer? (yes)(y)
or try again? (no)(n) ''')
            if showans in ["yes", "y", "Yes", "Y"]:
                invtimer()
                print("The answer is " + str(num1 * num2) + "!")
                break
            elif showans in ["no", "n", "No", "N"]:
                loop == False
            else:
                print("That is not an option! ") 
                loop == False
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number! ")
```

I need help with getting the second loop ==  False to link back the fist while loop. when I run it, it keeps going back to the second while loop.

Comment: Your indentation seems wrong. Can you edit your question and fix it.

Comment: `print("loop", loop)` at the end of the inner loop would show you that loop is still `True` and then you could take a closer look (and even another print) where you _think_ you assign it to false.

Comment: @furthoc: Your indentation looks somehow broken, but i have to ask: ...why the second loop? It seems like you catch three possible cases for `showans` and every one of it should exit the loop. So, why the loop in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You were using the `==` operator. This operator is only meant to be used in conditional statements and loops, not when assigning variables. When you assign `False` to a variable use `=` instead

```
while loop == True:                                                                             #creates loop, and uses previously defined 'loop'
    try:
        ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? "))      #asks question and requires a user input
        correct = (ans == num1 * num2)
        if correct:
            invtimer()
            print("You are correct! ")
            break                                                                               #if the answer is correct, it prints 'You are correct!' and breaks to avoid the loop
        else:
            invtimer()
        while loop == True:
            showans = input('''Wrong answer.
Would you like to see the answer? (yes)(y)
or try again? (no)(n) ''')
            if showans in ["yes", "y", "Yes", "Y"]:
                invtimer()
                print("The answer is " + str(num1 * num2) + "!")
                break
            elif showans in ["no", "n", "No", "N"]:
                loop = False
            else:
                print("That is not an option! ") 
                loop = False
    except ValueError:
        print("That is not a number! ")
```